# Need to add a menu option to app

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to add a menu option that will clear all of the `EditText` boxes. Right now I have it as a Toast item, that pops up for a short period, but I need it to clear out any text that was entered.

MainActivity

```
package 340.converter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    final EditText NumKnots = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumKnots);
    final EditText NumMPH = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumMPH);
    Button MPHConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MPHConv);

    MPHConvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double Knots = Double.valueOf(NumKnots.getText().toString());
            double MPH = Knots * 1.15078;
            NumMPH.setText(String.valueOf(MPH));

        }
    });

    final EditText NumNMile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumNMile);
    final EditText NumSMiles = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumSMiles);
    Button SMilesConv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SMilesConv);

    SMilesConv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double NMile = Double.valueOf(NumNMile.getText().toString());
            double SMiles = NMile * 1.15078;
            NumSMiles.setText(String.valueOf(SMiles));

        }
    });

    final EditText NumCHead = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumCHead);
    final EditText NumRHead = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumRHead);
    Button RHeadConv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RHeadConv);

    RHeadConv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double CHead = Double.valueOf(NumCHead.getText().toString());
            double RHead = CHead + 180;
            NumRHead.setText(String.valueOf(RHead));

        }
    });
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_Clear)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.action_Clear, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    else if(id == R.id.action_About)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created by:  \n For:  \n Year Created: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

content_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/txtKnots"
    android:id="@+id/txtKnots"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MPHConv"
    android:id="@+id/MPHConv"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtKnots"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/txtMPH"
    android:id="@+id/txtMPH"
    android:layout_below="@+id/MPHConv"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/txtNMiles"
    android:id="@+id/txtNMiles"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtMPH"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/SMilesConv"
    android:id="@+id/SMilesConv"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNMiles"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/txtSMile"
    android:id="@+id/txtSMile"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SMilesConv"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/txtCHead"
    android:id="@+id/txtCHead"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtSMile"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/RHeadConv"
    android:id="@+id/RHeadConv"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtCHead"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/txtRHead"
    android:id="@+id/txtRHead"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RHeadConv"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/NumKnots"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtRHead"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtRHead" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/NumMPH"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtNMiles"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/NumKnots"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/NumKnots"
    android:layout_below="@+id/NumKnots"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/NumKnots"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/NumKnots" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/NumNMile"
    android:layout_above="@+id/SMilesConv"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/NumMPH"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/NumMPH"
    android:layout_below="@+id/NumMPH"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/NumMPH"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/NumMPH" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/NumSMiles"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSMile"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/NumNMile"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/NumNMile"
    android:layout_below="@+id/NumNMile"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/NumNMile"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/NumNMile" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/NumCHead"
    android:layout_above="@+id/RHeadConv"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/NumSMiles"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/NumSMiles"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/NumSMiles" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/NumRHead"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtRHead"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/RHeadConv"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/NumCHead"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/NumCHead" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

strings

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Converter</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="action_Clear">Clear Screen</string>
<string name="action_About">About</string>
<string name="txtKnots">Knots</string>
<string name="txtMPH">MPH</string>
<string name="txtNMiles">Nautical Miles</string>
<string name="txtSMile">Statute Miles</string>
<string name="txtRHead">Reciprocal Heading</string>
<string name="txtCHead">Compass Heading</string>
<string name="MPHConv">Convert</string>
<string name="SMilesConv">Convert</string>
<string name="RHeadConv">Convert</string>
</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"     android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>




package 340.converter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    final EditText NumKnots = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumKnots);
    final EditText NumMPH = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumMPH);
    Button MPHConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MPHConv);

    MPHConvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double Knots = Double.valueOf(NumKnots.getText().toString());
            double MPH = Knots * 1.15078;
            NumMPH.setText(String.valueOf(MPH));

        }
    });

    final EditText NumNMile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumNMile);
    final EditText NumSMiles = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumSMiles);
    Button SMilesConv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SMilesConv);

    SMilesConv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double NMile = Double.valueOf(NumNMile.getText().toString());
            double SMiles = NMile * 1.15078;
            NumSMiles.setText(String.valueOf(SMiles));

        }
    });

    final EditText NumCHead = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumCHead);
    final EditText NumRHead = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumRHead);
    Button RHeadConv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RHeadConv);

    RHeadConv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double CHead = Double.valueOf(NumCHead.getText().toString());
            double RHead = CHead + 180;
            NumRHead.setText(String.valueOf(RHead));

        }
    });
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_About)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created by: \n For: \n Year Created: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    android.view.ViewGroup group = (android.view.ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.action_Clear);
    for (int k = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); k < count; k++)
    {
        View view = group.getChildAt(k);
        if (view instanceof EditText)
        {
            ((EditText)view).setText("");
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

11-09 12:03:57.725 28029-28029/340.converter W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0caeb20)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime: Process: 340.converter, PID: 28029
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at 340.converter.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:98)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:361)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:147)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:73)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:180)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:761)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:191)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-09 12:04:01.415 28029-28029/340.converter E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 12:04:01.425 1254-1376/system_process D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8cb5ba0, tid 1376

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all children in a view group and clear all the EditText fields:

```
ViewGroup vgroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
for (int k = 0, k < vgroup.getChildCount(); k++) 
{
    View view = vgroup.getChildAt(k);
    if (view instanceof EditText) 
    {
        ((EditText)view).setText(""); field
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do I put that?

Comment: "Right now I have it as a Toast item, that pops up for a short period, but I need it to clear out any text that was entered." - from your question it sounds like it needs to be where your toast is

Comment: This is what I put in, but it crashes when I clear screen.

@Override  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { int id = item.getItemId(); if (id == R.id.action_About) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created by: \n For: \n Year Created: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); return true; }android.view.ViewGroup group = (android.view.ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.action_Clear);for (int k = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); k < count; k++) {View view = group.getChildAt(k); if (view instanceof EditText){(EditText)view).setText("");}}return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); } }

Comment: Doesn't it need to be inside the if block? But what is the error?

Comment: Yes, but the error should be posted to the logcat. There should be a stacktrace. This would be helpful information.

Comment: I could take a guess that you forgot to change `R.id.linearLayout` for the actual id of your layout. Did you remember to change this?

Comment: These are the first messages that appear in the logcat:

eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
Exception dispatching input event
Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: This isn't all too helpful. Only the lines related to your project are interesting. Can you screenshot your logcat?

Comment: I can, but I don't think I can post pics on reply?

Comment: You can either update your original question with the updated code, or upload the screenshot somewhere and link it in this comment.

Comment: I posted 2 of them. It won't let me post 3 pics though.

Comment: I said that you should screenshot the code if you were going to include it in this comment section. Since you updated your question, you should include the actual stack trace (so copy and paste), instead of screenshots....

Comment: Include the new code as well so I can see where you've put it.

Comment: Ok sorry, I will change it

Comment: What about it is throwing a `nullpointerexception`? Did you try stepping through it line-by-line? I also changed the `for loop` condition to `for (int k = 0, k < vgroup.getChildCount(); k++) ` if you want to give that a try. Also, I'm trying to help you. I'd appreciate it if you didn't ask the same question again (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643276/app-quits-unexpectedly)

Comment: I also notice you changed the id from a potential layout from your xml to a string from your `String.xml`. It needs to be the id of a layout. What you need to do is give your `relativeLayout` an id (so something like `android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"`) and change your `ViewGroup` line to match it. So something like `android.view.ViewGroup group = (android.view.ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);`. The purpose of this is that it will loop through all `EditText` fields in your layout.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help me! I am sorry and didn't realize it was an issue, posting my question again. When I make the changes, the for loop is now showing errors. Also, what I make the changes to R.id.Layout, how will it know to activate the clear screen action? Again, I am sorry!

Comment: That's ok. What are the errors in the `for` loop? Just change it back if it doesn't work (I haven't compiled any of this code). Ok, an explanation.. so from the code you can see that a group is trying to be made, and it uses an ID as a parameter. You currently have the ID as a string.xml, and that doesn't make sense because how does a string relate to your `editTexts`? This is why it needs to be the ID of a layout. It looks at this layout and groups all the EditText fields within it. This is how it is able to loop through them and clear the text

Comment: In addition, you need to have this code in an `if` statement like you originally had (I don't know why you deleted it..?) So `if (id == R.id.action_clear) { do the code}`

Comment: This is what I changed it to,
`if (id == R.id.action_Clear)
        for (int k = 0, k < vgroup.getChildCount(); k++)
        android.view.ViewGroup vgroup = (android.view.ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.Layout1);`
I get errors for k, says its already defined in the scope, and vgroup.get…. it says it cannot resolve symbol ‘vgroup’

Comment: And.. did it work? I'm guessing you also gave your relativelayout that ID (Layout1) in your xml

Comment: Yes, in content_main.xml, `android:id="@+id/Layout1"`

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. An up-vote and the accepted answer is always welcome if you found this useful!